# Oracle / SQL Developer displaying (null) in column

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have any oracle table that sometimes has valid null values is some cells.  In SQL Developer it displays in the null cell as (null).  This is not a problem but in a grid I have on a jsp page is also displays as (null) and I need it just to be blank.  NVL does not work unless I use a space.  I was wondering if there is an oracle setting or something to have valid null cells just be blank ?  thank you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Modifying SQL Developer Preferences**

Jeff Smith, the product manager for SQL Developer, blogged about this here, [http://www.thatjeffsmith.com](http://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2011/11/sql-developer-quick-tip-take-the-guess-work-out-of-null/).

Just navigate to the SQL Developer tool bar as follows:

**Preferences>Database>Advanced**

and change the value in the field, "Display Null Value As", to nothing as seen here:
[image]

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

With a jsp, one could create a method for scenarios where a column is null (to display the null as other than '(null)').

Comment: this did fix it in sql developer but it still displays the same way on the form (null).  Is there a setting in oracle to fix this?

Comment: I would just add a method to address nulls with the jsp.